# nmake u1034 separator missing

Tags: nmake, separator

I've tried to execute make file with nmake in dos-prompt and got the following message:

> makefile.in(145) : fatal error U1034: syntax error : separator missing

I took a look into the make file and the line 145 says:

> ifeq (@INSTALINFO_FOUND@,yes)

I have absolutely no clue how to fix this ... Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Makefile.in` indicates the build system you should use is the GNU autotools. These will pre-process your files into GNU format makefile(s). You are then expected to use GNU make with these makefiles.

`nmake` is a completely different beast and will not be compatible with these files.

I suggest you investigate whether your package is buildable using Microsft tools (hunt out words like *nmake* or *Visual Studio* or *Windows* etc., in its documentation). Your other alternative is to grab a windows port of the Autotools. Cygwin is good, but here be dragons for the unwary.